# Fix values for multiple columns conditions

Tags: python, pandas

```
            A         B       C    D
0  2002-01-13  15:00:00  Joseph  3.9
1  2002-01-13  15:00:00    Emma  1.9
2  2002-01-13  16:00:00  Joseph  8.0
3  2002-01-13  16:00:00    Emma  9.0
4  2002-01-14  15:00:00  Joseph  0.2
5  2002-01-14  15:00:00    Emma  7.0
6  2002-01-14  16:00:00  Joseph  1.6
7  2002-01-14  16:00:00    Emma  3.4
```

I want to get a new `df["E"]` column, that fixes the "Joseph" and "Emma" *D values* at 15:00:00, to the rest of each day.

The output should be:

```
            A         B       C    D     E
0  2002-01-13  15:00:00  Joseph  3.9   3.9
1  2002-01-13  15:00:00    Emma  1.9   1.9
2  2002-01-13  16:00:00  Joseph  8.0   3.9
3  2002-01-13  16:00:00    Emma  9.0   3.9
4  2002-01-14  15:00:00  Joseph  0.2   0.2
5  2002-01-14  15:00:00    Emma  7.0   7.0
6  2002-01-14  16:00:00  Joseph  1.6   0.2
7  2002-01-14  16:00:00    Emma  3.4   7.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want to `groupby` on `A` and `C` and then use `transform` + `first` on `D`.

```
df['E'] = df.groupby(['A', 'C']).D.transform('first')
df

            A         B       C    D    E
0  2002-01-13  15:00:00  Joseph  3.9  3.9
1  2002-01-13  15:00:00    Emma  1.9  1.9
2  2002-01-13  16:00:00  Joseph  8.0  3.9
3  2002-01-13  16:00:00    Emma  9.0  1.9
4  2002-01-14  15:00:00  Joseph  0.2  0.2
5  2002-01-14  15:00:00    Emma  7.0  7.0
6  2002-01-14  16:00:00  Joseph  1.6  0.2
7  2002-01-14  16:00:00    Emma  3.4  7.0
```

If entries begin earlier than `15:00:00`, mask `D` first and then `transform`:

```
df['E'] = df.assign(
        D=df.D.mask(df.B.ne('15:00:00'))
 ).groupby(['A', 'C']).D.transform('first')

df
            A         B       C    D    E
0  2002-01-13  15:00:00  Joseph  3.9  3.9
1  2002-01-13  15:00:00    Emma  1.9  1.9
2  2002-01-13  16:00:00  Joseph  8.0  3.9
3  2002-01-13  16:00:00    Emma  9.0  1.9
4  2002-01-14  15:00:00  Joseph  0.2  0.2
5  2002-01-14  15:00:00    Emma  7.0  7.0
6  2002-01-14  16:00:00  Joseph  1.6  0.2
7  2002-01-14  16:00:00    Emma  3.4  7.0
```